# how to display image on google map using latitude and longitude from sql database?

Tags: c#, google-maps

i just want show image on google map using latitude and longitude getting value from database and display on map.Please suggest me how it will done. using java scripts. Thanks in advance.(i will glad if you will give example in asp.net c#)

it should look like this page. 
https://500px.com/map

it will look like similar below photo.
[ATTACH IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Got26.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really good resource on CodeProject that includes an example for overlaying an image in Google Maps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20590/Google-Maps-in-HTML-ASP-NET-PHP-JSP-etc-with-ease

Comment: thanks @Whitey for your response but this not not what i want. i request to you if you see the attach image and suggest any solution of it. thanks once again.

Comment: That page shows exactly how to do that, take a look at #5 in the Frequently Asked Questions.